# How can I test Perl applications using a changing system time?

Tags: perl, datetime, testing, mocking

I have a web application that I want to run some system tests on, and in order to do that I'm going to need to move the system time around.  The application used DateTime all the way through.

Has anyone got any recommendations for how to change the time that DateTime->now reports?  The only thing that comes to mind is subclassing DateTime and messing about with all the 'use' lines, but this seems rather invasive.

Note on answers:

All three will work fine, but the Hook::LexWrap one is the one I've chosen because (a) I want to move the clock rather than jiggle it a bit (which is more the purpose of what Time::Mock and friends do); (b) I do, consistently, use DateTime, and I'm happy to have errors come out if I've accidentally *not* used it; and (c) Hook::LexWrap is simply more elegant than a hack in the symbol table, for all that it does the same thing.  (Also, it turns out to be a dependency of some module I already installed, so I didn't even have to CPAN it...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use code injection via [Hook::LexWrap](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Hook-LexWrap/lib/Hook/LexWrap.pm) to intercept the now() method.

```
use Hook::LexWrap;

use DateTime;

# Use real now
test();

{
    my $wrapper = wrap 'DateTime::now',
        post => sub {
            $_[-1] = DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => 0 );
        };

    # Use fake now
    test();

}

# use real now again
test();

sub test {
    my $now = DateTime->now;

    print "The time is $now\n";
}
```

Comment: Interesting, and the doc pointer was very helpful.  I would recommend mentioning the non-scoped version in the answer as well, since that what I was originally looking for, but both versions will be useful to me.

Answer (score 11):

Rather than taking the high-level approach and wrapping `DateTime` specifically, you might want to look into the modules [Test::MockTime](http://search.cpan.org/~ddick/Test-MockTime-0.12/lib/Test/MockTime.pod) and [Time::Mock](http://search.cpan.org/~ewilhelm/Time-Mock-v0.0.2/lib/Time/Mock.pm), which override the low-level functions that `DateTime` etc. make use of, and (with any luck) will do the right thing on *any* time-sensitive code. To me it seems like a more robust way to test.

Comment: This seems like the best solution.  The tests will continue to work when the tested code switches to a different library for date and time handling.

Comment: Indeed so, though in this case, I want to standardise on DateTime throughout the application.  So having a test that fails when not using DateTime is a good thing.

Answer (score 4):

I think Hook::LexWrap is overkill for this situation.  It's easier to just redefine such a simple function.

```
use DateTime;

my $offset;

BEGIN {
  $offset = 24 * 60 * 60; # Pretend it's tomorrow

  no warnings 'redefine';

  sub DateTime::now
  {
    shift->from_epoch( epoch => ($offset + scalar time), @_ )
  }
} # end BEGIN
```

You can replace `my $offset` with `our $offset` if you need to access the `$offset` from outside the file which contains this code.

You can adjust `$offset` at any time, if you want to change DateTime's idea of the current time during the run.

The calculation of `$offset` should probably be more complicated than shown above.  For example, to set the "current time" to an absolute time:

```
my $want = DateTime->new(
   year   => 2009,
   month  => 9,
   day    => 14,
   hour   => 12,
   minute => 0,
   second => 0,
   time_zone => 'America/Chicago',
);

my $current = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch => scalar time);

$offset = $want->subtract_datetime_absolute($current)->in_units('seconds');
```

But you probably do want to calculate a fixed number of seconds to add to the current time, so that time will advance normally after that.  The problem with using `add( days => 1 );` in the redefined `now` method is that things like DST changes will cause the time to jump at the wrong pseudotime.

Comment: What you show works fine if you only have to override now() to one behavior during the entire run.  If the OP is changing the behavior of now() repeatedly, and over narrow portions of the test suite, I believe H::LW is a better choice.  Also, to pretend it's tomorrow, wouldn't it be better to use DateTime's facilities and do it right?   DateTime->now->add( days => 1 );

Comment: Well, you can easily change `$offset` at any time during the run.  As for using `add` instead, that depends on exactly what you're trying to do.  I was just giving one example of a possible new definition.

Comment: Change "my $offset = ..." to "our $_offset = ...", and then the test script can twiddle $DateTime::_offset as much as it likes.

Comment: daotoad: give the ->add() method a try and let us know when it succeeds.

Comment: @ysth, you are correct, I did inadvertently create an infinite recursion by calling `now()`.  So, the trivial fix is `DateTime->from_epoch( epoch => time )->add( days =>1 );` But the fundamental point, that adding 86400 seconds is a bad way to move forward exactly one day, is still true.  The difficulties that arise when doing date time math is one of the key reasons to use DateTime rather than just hacking something together with time().

Comment: You should do all of your definitions in a BEGIN to ensure nothing gets to call the real ones.

Answer (score 1):

When designing a new class with testability in mind, the ideal solution is to be able to inject new date objects.

However, for existing code using `DateTime->now` and `DateTime->today` a possible, suitably scoped, solution is below. I include it here as a way to do this without introducing Hook::LexWrap as a dependency and without affecting the behaviour globally.

```
{
    no strict 'refs';
    no warnings 'redefine';
    local *{'DateTime::today'} = sub {
        return DateTime->new(
            year  => 2012,
            month => 5,
            day   => 31
        );
    };
    say DateTime->today->ymd(); # 2012-05-31
};

say DateTime->today->ymd(); # today
```